# Most natural definition of Euclidean geometry

Tags: euclidean-geometry

What is the "least" amount of structure in terms of axioms and assumptions that is needed to define a Euclidean geometry.

For example, is any set {p} a with  a not  necessarily explicitly defined metric d from {p}x{p} to R an Euclidean space if it satisfies the following axioms :

For every p1, p2 in {p} there always exists a set of points P containing p1,p2 such that for any points p1, p2, p3 in P if d(p2, p3) < d(p1, p3) > d(p1, p2,) than d(p1, p3)=d(p1, p2)+d(p2, p3)

For any such set P and for any point p not in P there is always a set(line) P2  such that given any pair (p1, p2) where p1 is from P and p2 is from P2, there is number d such d is the minimal value of the metric for any such pair.

With the variation of this last property geometry should become non Euclidean.

Comment: You switch between calling your set {p} and p and P.  Are those all the same thing?  What does it mean for a metric to be explicitly defined (or not)?

Comment: P is a "straight line" subset of {p} which is a set of some" points" p

Comment: Non explicit just means there is no explicit way to calculate d(p1, p2), it's simply a given, just a binary relation on {p}

Answer (score 3):

It depends on what you take for granted.

[Tarski's axiomatic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarski%27s_axioms) only relies on first order logic and uses 10 axioms. With an eleventh continuity axiom, it is complete.

[Birkhoff's axiomatic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birkhoff%27s_axioms) takes the properties of the real numbers as granted and uses 5 postulates. Some variation of it is still in use in highschools in America. This is probably what you want since your post makes use of a distance $d$ that relies on some axiomatics for the real numbers.

[Hilbert's axioms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%27s_axioms) played an important role at the beginning of the XXe century and possesses 20 axioms. It is probably the closest to Euclid's axiomatic.

There are many other axiomatic systems such as Bachmann's which is geared toward group theory and contains 5 axioms. Arguably, for an axiomatic to qualify as a complete axiomatic of elementary geometry, it should at least contain Tarski's axioms as theorems.

Comment: So any system using reals has to contain brichofs axioms?

Comment: So the example in the equestion is incomplete or inconsistent with Euclidean geometry?

Comment: Indeed, any subset of the euclidean plane satisfies your axioms. You need more axioms to get the whole plane. A way to show that a system of axioms defines the well-known euclidean space modeled on ${\bf R}^2$ is to show that Birkhoff (not brichofs) axioms are theorems in your axiomatic.